# Low Search - Filter by Group Id

Tags: low-search

Channels have author id. Authors are associated with groups (member).

Is it possible to filter collection entries based on group id in Low Search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native channel:entries tag supports the `group_id=""` parameter ([see the docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#group-id)), which means you can filter Low Search results by group ID as well. Simply add it as an input field to your search form, for example:

```
<select name="group_id">
    <option value="">All groups</option>
    <option value="1">SuperAdmins</option>
    <option value="x">Group X</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: I see. My mistake then was setting the name to "search:group_id". No need for the "search:" prefix.